When can one matrix be obtained from another through row and column permutations?
Suppose that I have two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that:

Each entry in both of them is a natural number,
They have the same dimensions,
They have the same numbers with the same frequencies,
But they have these numbers in different entries.

Then, can I obtain matrix A from matrix B just by performing row and column permutations?
EXAMPLE: consider these matrices:
Matrix B
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 & 2\\
4 & 2 & 1\\
2 & 4 & 3\\
1 & 3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
Matrix B
\begin{pmatrix}
   3 & 2 & 1\\
   4 & 1 & 2\\
   1 & 3 & 4\\
   2 & 4 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
QUESTION: Can I obtain matrix B from matrix A through column and row permutations?

There probably is no easy criterion, but there is an invariant and an algorithm. The multiset of row sums and the multiset of column sums will be invariant.
For the algorithm, just swap the rows and swap the columns so that the rows are minimal alphabetically. If the two match then the permutations that sort them tell you how to transform one into the other.

No, for example consider the matrices
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
    1 & 2\\
    1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
    1 & 2\\
    2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$.
You can’t use row and column permutations to go from one to the other since the first one has zero-determinant, and the second one has non-zero determinant.

Thank you for your answer. Can you state under which conditions (if any) it’s possible to obtain one matrix from another through column and row permutations?

I don’t know of a nice general characterization unfortunately.
